# Disk and Ram Memory size

Tags: lamp, memory-usage

I need to know  the disk size and the ram size of LAMP + Chrome. How can I check it... on ubuntu 11.x and 12.x

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

disc size: `df -h` and disc usage `du -h` (there are many other options)